# .Distinct() and .ToList() not available with Dapper Multi Map inside service method

Tags: c#, lambda, dapper

I am using Dapper Multi Mapping to return a collection of Invoices. Each invoice contains a collection of InvoiceItems. Here are the models.

```
public class InvoiceModel
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }

    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public List<InvoiceItemModel> InvoiceItems { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceItemModel
{
    public int InvoiceItemId { get; set; }

    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }

    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

I find that if I place the code to get the data and map the objects directly in the controller then everything works fine. However, I would like to place this code into a service that is called from the controller. When I place the code in a service the code does not work. In fact, I cannot even use the lambda extensions `Distinct()` or `ToList()` from within the method that is part of the service.

**This code works** - Notice how it is right inside the API controller

```
public List<InvoiceModel> GetInvoiceTest(int invoiceId)
{
    using (IDbConnection db = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(SqlDataAccess.LoadConnectionString("InvoiceDb")))
    {
        try
        {
            string sql = @"SELECT 
                            Invoice.InvoiceId,
                            Invoice.Customer AS CustomerName,
                            InvoiceItem.InvoiceItemId,
                            InvoiceItem.InvoiceId,
                            InvoiceItem.[Name] AS ItemName,
                            InvoiceItem.Quantity
                        FROM Invoice
                        LEFT JOIN InvoiceItem ON Invoice.InvoiceId = InvoiceItem.InvoiceId
                        WHERE Invoice.InvoiceId = " + invoiceId;

            var invoiceDictionary = new Dictionary<int, InvoiceModel>();

            var invoices = db.Query<InvoiceModel, InvoiceItemModel, InvoiceModel>(
                sql,
                (invoiceModel, invoiceItemModel) =>
                {
                    InvoiceModel invoiceEntry;

                    if (!invoiceDictionary.TryGetValue(invoiceModel.InvoiceId, out invoiceEntry))
                    {
                        invoiceEntry = invoiceModel;
                        invoiceEntry.InvoiceItems = new List<InvoiceItemModel>();
                        invoiceDictionary.Add(invoiceEntry.InvoiceId, invoiceEntry);
                    }

                    invoiceEntry.InvoiceItems.Add(invoiceItemModel);
                    return invoiceEntry;
                },
                splitOn: "InvoiceItemId").Distinct().ToList();

            return invoices;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("", "Get Invoice Error", new { InvoiceId = invoiceId }, ex);
            throw new Exception("Error occured while trying to obtain Invoice", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I place this same code within a static method contained in a service class I find I am unable to use `.Distinct().ToList();`. I find I can change the extension to `.AsList();` but the results come out as duplicates.

Here is the method within the service.

```
public static List<InvoiceModel> GetInvoices(int invoiceId)
{
  using (...)
  {
    // Same code as above starting with the using statement
    ...
    //splitOn: "InvoiceItemId").Distinct().ToList(); // Unavailable
    splitOn: "InvoiceItemId").AsList(); // Only option available
  }
}
```

Does it have to do with the service method being `static`?

Note: I apologize for the length of the post. I tried pairing it down as much as I could but I felt it best to list the models.

Comment: `.Distinct()` and `.ToList()` are methods defined in the class `System.Linq.Enumerable` which are found in the `System.Linq` namespace which is contained in the `System.Linq.dll` assembly.  Are you sure you have this assembly referenced in your service and have imported the `System.Linq` namespace?

Comment: @Chris - That was it. I added `using  System.Linq;` and I was able to add the Distinct() and ToList(). For some reason I thought they were available with the default using statements. Please add it as an answer and I will mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something on these lines

```
  var invoices = db.QueryAsync<InvoiceModel, InvoiceItemModel, InvoiceModel>(
                    sql,
                    (invoiceModel, invoiceItemModel) =>
                    {
                        InvoiceModel invoiceEntry;

                        if (!invoiceDictionary.TryGetValue(invoiceModel.InvoiceId, out invoiceEntry))
                        {
                            invoiceEntry = invoiceModel;
                            invoiceEntry.InvoiceItems = new List<InvoiceItemModel>();
                            invoiceDictionary.Add(invoiceEntry.InvoiceId, invoiceEntry);
                        }

                        invoiceEntry.InvoiceItems.Add(invoiceItemModel);
                        return invoiceEntry;
                    },
                    null,
                    null,
                    true,
                    splitOn: "InvoiceItemId",
                    999)
                    .Result
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToList();
```

Thank you